# Format of /proc/mounts?

Tags: mount

There isn't much to say here :-)
Where do I find information regarding the format used in the file `/proc/mounts`?

My current guess is the following (delimited by a single space):

```
DEVICE PATH FILESYSTEM FLAGS_DELIMITED_BY_COMMAS ??? ???
```

I'm rather puzzled about the last two '???', though. Help is very appreciated...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format is the same as in `/etc/fstab`. The information for `/etc/fstab` can be found by `man fstab` or on [this page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab).

It says:

> The  fifth  field,  (fs_freq),  is 
>   used for these filesystems by the
>   dump(8) command to determine which
>   filesystems need to be dumped.  If the
>   fifth field is not present, a value of zero is returned and dump will
>   assume that the filesystem does not
>   need to be dumped.
>
> The sixth field, (fs_passno), is used by the fsck(8) program to
>   determine the order in which
>   filesystem checks are done at  reboot 
>   time. The root filesystem should be specified with a fs_passno of 1, and other
>   filesystems should have a fs_passno of 2.  Filesystems within a drive will be checked
>   sequentially, but filesystems on different drives will be checked at
>   the same time to utilize parallelism
>   available in the hardware. If the sixth field is not present or zero, 
>   a value of zero is returned and fsck
>   will assume that the filesystem does
>   not need to be checked.